# How to implement lazy loading for multiple modules

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, requirejs, lazy-loading, oclazyload

I need to implement lazy loading for my project which uses AngularJs, RequireJs, Grunt.This is a very large project and it is divided into multiple modules containing their separate controller, service and routing.js files. I tried my hands on OcLazyLoad but it works only if I maintain a single routing file for entire project.
But my manager says no for having a single routing file. 
Is there any other lazy loader available I can try or any grunt plugin to merge all routing files to one on build time.

We follow this kind of structure in the project:

```
App

|--js
    |-
-app.js
    |--bootstrap.js
    |--main.js

|--modules
    |--login
        |--controller.js
        |--routing.js
        |--service.js
    |--agent
        |--orders
            |--controller.js
            |--routing.js
            |--service.js
        |--controller.js
        |--routing.js
        |--service.js
    |--admin
        |--controller.js
        |--routing.js
        |--service.js
```

Comment: What does your manager suggest?

Comment: He suggested to look for an alternative to OcLazyLoad.  I am not sure if any other lazyloader will work for independent routings